# CentOS 6.5 & Mono 3.2.8 : WARNING: libMonoPosixHelper.so

Tags: c#, mono, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to make NuGet work under a fresh install of CentOS 6.5 using Mono 3.2.8. However when I try to restore the packages, I get a `WARNING: libMonoPosixHelper.so` warning message, followed by `Unable to read package from path <package_Name>.nupkg` and `Unable to find version <some version> of package <next package>` error messages. This works fine under Ubuntu 14.04 using the same Mono version.

Here are the output:

```
[root@folke folke-app]# mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (tarball Wed Apr 23 20:44:34 CEST 2014)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

I cloned this .NET project (I tried with others, same result) :

```
[root@folke folke-app]# git clone https://github.com/acastaner/harnet.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/folke-app/harnet/.git/
remote: Reusing existing pack: 273, done.
remote: Total 273 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (273/273), 752.91 KiB | 429 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (170/170), done.
```

But when I try to NuGet restore I get this:

```
[root@folke folke-app]# mono nuget.exe restore harnet/harnet/packages.config -SolutionDirectory harnet/
WARNING: libMonoPosixHelper.so
Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8'.
Unable to read package from path 'Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.8.nupkg'.
Unable to find version '1.2.0' of package 'NodaTime'.
```

I *have* run the `mozroots --import --sync` command that is typically associated with NuGet errors on Linux.

Update:

I also executed certmgr, no luck:

```
certmgr -ssl -m https://go.microsoft.com
certmgr -ssl -m https://nugetgallery.blob.core.windows.net
certmgr -ssl -m https://nuget.org
```

Comment: Did you install Mono from a repository, or did you build it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

nuget.exe is not working because mono is not able to find the library called libMonoPosixHelper.so (I do not think you may run mono/.NET applications without that library)

Firts of all, you should search for the required library in your file system.

Then, you could try something like this (from the command-line interface):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/directory/where/missing/library/was/found/
mono nuget.exe whatever_you_want_to_do
```

There is more information about what LD_LIBRARY_PATH is for following this link: [man ld](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled Mono from source, `libMonoPosixHelper.so` is likely in `/usr/local/lib`.

To make sure libraries are loaded from that directory, run (as root):

```
echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf
ldconfig
```

It also might be worth reading through this page on [setting up a Mono environment](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/parallel-mono-environments/#setting-up-a-build-environment) to see which environment variables Mono uses to find libraries.